# How to transparently substitute sha1sum for shasum in sh shell?

Tags: macos, bash, perl, sh, sha1

I have a test that needs to run on multiple platforms.  On all other platforms, the test uses `sha1sum`, but on my Mac OSX El Capitan, there is no such program installed, but `shasum` works fine as a substitute.

I tried to create a link from `/usr/bin/sha1sum` to `/usr/bin/shasum`, but that fails, even as root:

```
bash-3.2$ cd /usr/bin
bash-3.2$ sudo ln shasum sha1sum
ln: sha1sum: Operation not permitted
```

I then put it in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
bash-3.2$ cd /usr/local/bin
bash-3.2$ ln -s /usr/bin/shasum sha1sum
```

And it seems to work:

```
bash-3.2$ sha1sum -c files.sha1sum
smallData.txt: OK
```

But, my test harness, now finding sha1sum, still fails:

```
perl version 5.18.2 can't run /usr/local/bin/sha1sum.  Try the alternative(s):

(Error: no alternatives found)

Run "man perl" for more information about multiple version support in
Mac OS X.
```

I also tried using `alias sha1sum=shasum` but the harness fails with:

```
sh: line 1: sha1sum: command not found
```

I found that my harness is failing because it is using `sh` instead of `bash`.

```
sh-3.2$ sha1sum -c files.sha1sum
perl version 5.18.2 can't run /usr/local/bin/sha1sum.  Try the alternative(s):

(Error: no alternatives found)

Run "man perl" for more information about multiple version support in
Mac OS X.
sh-3.2$ shasum -c files.sha1sum
smallData.txt: OK
```

So why is it that `sha1sum` fails to run under `sh` but `shasum` works and `sha1sum` works under `bash` and how can I get `sha1sum` to run under `sh`?

I'm also confused as to why this fails:

```
bash-3.2$ echo "sha1sum -c files.sha1sum" | bash
perl version 5.18.2 can't run /usr/local/bin/sha1sum.  Try the alternative(s):

(Error: no alternatives found)

Run "man perl" for more information about multiple version support in
Mac OS X.
```

I now notice this comment in the `/usr/bin/shasum` file:

```
The contents of this script should normally never run!  The perl wrapper
should pick the correct script in /usr/bin by appending the appropriate version.
You can try appending the appropriate perl version number.  See perlmacosx.pod
for more information about multiple version support in Mac OS X.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is the link to the the version of `shasum` with the `perl` version appended:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/shasum5.18 sha1sum
```

Or to alias to it:

```
alias sha1sum=shasum5.18
```

Comment: Or you could test for Darwin with `uname -s` and assign `shasum5.18` to a variable `sha1sum` in you script.

Comment: @fd0 Sounds like a better answer, why not post it?

Comment: I don't have a clear sense of what your script(s) look like in your test harness.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "" | $(which shasum 2>/dev/null || which sha1sum 2>/dev/null)
```

output:

```
adc83b19e793491b1c6ea0fd8b46cd9f32e592fc  -
```

on either MacOS/Darwin or Linux

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.  (I believe that you’ve misunderstood the question.)   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.